# How to override global stylesheet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

In a nutshell, there's a global stylesheet:

```
a { font-family: Arial; }
```

I want to use a different font family for a particular link:

```
<a href="..." style="font-family: Helvetica;">...</a>
```

or

```
<span style="font-family: Helvetica;"><a href="...">...</a></span>
```

but nothing works. Is there an easy way to do this?

P.S. I'm dynamically (via PHP) assign different fonts to different links, so creating a special class is not an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have a specific font named Helvetica, you should realise that on some platforms (such as Windows, via [FontSubstitutes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757457.aspx)), Helvetica is aliased to Arial. That might be the source of the problem. Try another font and see.

Answer (score 6):

Your first attempt

```
  <a href="..." style="font-family: Helvetica;">...</a>
```

should have worked. Agree that you're probably missing a font. Inline styles have precedence over any other styles beside a user-defined style sheet. Here's the order of priorities for style definitions:

1. User defined style
2. Embedded or inline style sheet
3. Internal style sheet
4. External style sheet
5. Browser default style

Within a style sheet the priorities are as follows:

1. Anything marked !important
2. ## id
3. .class
4. element

In addition, you have the rule of greater specificity: `div a` overrides `a`.

Here's [a good article with more detail on the subject](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css).

@Kip's suggestion is your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

What you've written should work, unless the problem is what Chris pointed out,

When you get a pair of fonts for which this works correctly, you might consider that a better way of doing this would be to declare a class for the special links that somehow reminds yourself of **why** they need a separate font (maybe because you want them to be especially noticed?)

```
a { font-family: Arial; }
a .noticed { font-family: Helvetica; }
```

Then in HTML:

```
<a class="noticed" href="...">...</a>
```

Changing the font by creating a span tag around the link, or adding inline style to the link just smacks of the old days of `<font>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

element styles override global styles, so Chris Jester-Young is probably right and you don't actually have a Helvetica font; try a different font e.g. Courier or Times New Roman that you're certain exists